# New line chars in AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, unicode-escapes

I'm receiving a string from a windows application, the string is like this:

> "some text\r\nsome other text"

When I display the string in an alert dialog I see the following:

> "some text**rn**some other text"

The same string is showing correctly on a TextView, but not in an AlertDialog.

Please advice what I should do.

Best Regards.

**Edit**
This is what I tried so far:

```
CustomDialog.Builder dialog = new CustomDialog.Builder(this, "", getString(R.string.ok));
    dialog.contentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.content_color));
    dialog.titleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.content_color));
    dialog.positiveColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cpb_red));
    dialog.content(Message.replace("\r\n", "\n"));
    dialog.build().show();
```

**Edit 2:**
Let me explain more, I receive a JSON response from a WCF Service on Windows, parse JSON using [FastJson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson)
the text I receive from JSON after parsing is

> Server Will\r\n be down for maintenance

We just added \r\n for testing purpose but I'm sure someone will use them when sending data to Android. 
I have tried replacing using replace function, but no success.

Comment: Replace `\r\n` with `\n` and escape the slash

Comment: @TimCastelijns the replace function is not replacing them, I keep on seeing the same result

Comment: Then your code doesn't work. Can you show us how you tried that

Comment: @TimCastelijns check my edit please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the replace call, you also have to escape the slashes

Comment: @TimCastelijns I even tried "\\r\\n" unless you mean a different thing.

Comment: can you text ur response here which include \r\n ?

Comment: @Jigs please check my second edit

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the backslash in a `String#replaceAll` call works for me

```
String text = "some text\r\nsome other text";
System.out.println("preprocess text: " + text);
String post = text.replaceAll("\\r\\n", ":");
System.out.println("postprocess text: " + post);
```

Produces:

```
preprocess text: some text
some other text
postprocess text: some text:some other text
```

Comment: This didn't work, I even used Log.d and println I still see the same text I posted in my question. Ironically the same text works on an iPhone without having to replace anything :-/